# Possible to retrieve a symbolic variables value?

Tags: drake

I'm implementing a vector field method that should return a numeric value based on an (x, y) position, where x and y are both instances of `pydrake.symbolic.Variable`. I'm essentially looking to run f(x, y) -> float inside of the dynamics method of my `SymbolicVectorSystem`. Is it possible to evaluate the numeric value of x and y so that they can be used to compute f(x, y) numerically?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can just call `y = Evaluate(my_symbolic_expression)`, or `y = Evaluate(my_vector_or_matrix_of_symbolic_expressions)` which are using https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.symbolic.html#pydrake.symbolic.Evaluate with the default arguments.  This will return floats iff the expression is simply holding a constant value, or will throw an error if you still have symbols inside that need to be defined.