# RuntimeError when using pydrake.symbolic.Evaluate

Tags: drake

When trying to use evaluate to retrieve the numerical value of my continuous decision variable q, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: The following environment does not have an entry for the variable q(0,0)
```

Trying to get the value of a single entry in q (akin to the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61655092/possible-to-retrieve-a-symbolic-variables-value)), results in this error:

```
TypeError: Evaluate(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
1. (m: numpy.ndarray[object[m, n]], env: Dict[pydrake.symbolic.Variable, float] = {}, generator: pydrake.common._module_py.RandomGenerator = None) -> numpy.ndarray[numpy.float64[m, n]]
2. (m: numpy.ndarray[object[m, n]], env: Dict[pydrake.symbolic.Variable, float]) -> numpy.ndarray[numpy.float64[m, n]]

Invoked with: Variable('q(0,0)', Continuous)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Evaluate(expression)` will only provide output if the Expression is a constant.  To get the values of your decision variables, use `MathmaticalProgramResult.GetSolution`.

There are many great tutorials on using `MathematicalProgram` here: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/tutorials/README.md

Comment: Ah that's unfortunate, I need to somehow either retrieve the values from q (the position vector) and make a new array with these values or change my plant from symbolic to float (which isn't possible). And all this before/while solving the program, is there any function or method that could accomplish this?

Comment: I think that most workflows which make sense in this space are possible.  If your goal is to get a double out of the expression, then perhaps you want to call `Evaluate` but pass in the variable values (as a dictionary).  Or if your goal is to get another Expression, then perhaps you want to call `Substitute`?

Otherwise, I'll need a more careful explanation of your problem in order to help.

Comment: I've created continuous decision variables q to represent the position of a model in my plant. To make the plant reflect the value of these decision variables, I call plant.SetPositions(...) . After this, I need to obtain distance values through distance queries of my model in the new position to use in a constraint.

The problem with this is that I can't turn the symbolic plant generated, in order to use set position (drake requires the array and the plant to be of the same type), into a float for the query (as drake doesn't allow this). I'll make a detailed question if you need more info.

Comment: I see.  I didn't realize you were trying to push symbolic through the contact engine.  This is not supported yet; see the support tables here: https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_query_object.html#af3b16adde799eb804619dc86f3703f4f 

I've actually been working on adding that support, but most people think I'm crazy to try!  Collision queries are very "branchy", and not very friendly for symbolic analysis.

I suspect that you should be trying to write your constraint using autodiff, not symbolic.